# Custom font as fallback font for missing glyphs

Tags: ios, uikit, uifont, ctfont

I'm currently working on an app which displays some funky characters. They are proper unicode characters There is no system font that contains these glyphs on iOS, so I made a custom font that contains only these glyphs.

Now, **I don't want to replace** the system font with my custom font, but I want to have iOS load any missing glyphs from my custom font. Can iOS fallback to custom fonts?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you've gotten a reply by now, but the only way this is possible by using a custom font, is to have customise a "normal" fonts non-letter characters by replacing characters like U+2615 (Hot beverage) with your custom glyphs. Thus, you can use your custom font for all your UI, but you would need different characters than you use now to display your custom glyphs